# Babel loses code formatting

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to integrate `babel` through `gulp`.

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var es6 = require('babel-preset-es2015');
...
return gulp.src('path/to/my/source/file/js')
       .pipe(babel({presets:es6}))
...
```

When I run the compile task, my linter (`JSHint`) says that the line is too long and that I'm missing a line end.

Let's say that my source file is as following (please note the last empty line) :

```
(function(){
var myApp = angular.module('first-dependence',[
    'another-dependence',
    'and-another-dependence']
}();       
// Empty line here
```

Babel outputs it like this:

```
(function(){
var myApp = angular.module('first-dependence',['another-dependence','and-another-dependence']
}();
```

For me, he is ignoring the line returns inside the instructions and removes the last empty line.

Is it possible to tell `babel` to keep the formatting as it's and to only transcompile ?

Regards

Answer (score 8):

**You can't**. But you can try

- the [retainLines](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) option

  ```
  .pipe(babel({presets:es6, retainLines:true}))
  ```
- or to rely on source maps (see [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)).

But neither will preserve your white-space exactly as it is right now.

Comment: `retainLines:true` was exactly what I needed to preserve my comment positioning.  `gulp-beautify` handled the rest for me.